# How do I set up a Google Drive backup?

Tags: android, backup, google-drive-android-api

I want to synchronise a user's notes in his Google Drive. I read this article, but it doesn't work for me, I want to control the data synchronisation myself and run it whenever I want.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup

It should look something like this:[image]
Can you please tell me how I can implement this? I can't fully understand the Google Drive API V3

Comment: Did you develop your user's Notes app? Or is it a third-party/stock Notes app? As far as I know, the [Auto Backup](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup) docs is a guide for Android app developers on how to backup their app's data using _Auto Backup for Apps_

Comment: Yes, this is my note taking app, I want the user to be able to set up when to do a backup, once a day or once a week